# Couldn't connect SSMS using Windows authentication but can login using SQL Authentication

Tags: sql-server, authentication

This is real time serious issue. My production server was working fine till thursday then we had a weekend (fri & Sat). Today morning I got complaint saying couldn't connect to the database. I tried from local, no luck. When I take RDC (MSTSC), I can connect instantly.

But when I try connecting from Local, it is throwing the below error.

```
TITLE: Connect to Server ------------------------------ Cannot connect
to servernamevs\servername. ------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period
elapsed during the post-login phase. The connection could have timed
out while waiting for server to complete the login process and
respond; Or it could have timed out while attempting to create
multiple active connections. The duration spent while attempting to
connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=6;
handshake=4; [Login] initialization=0; authentication=5; [Post-Login]
complete=13990; (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)
```

Then, I failed over to another node then everybody can connect. Now I need to findout the reason. Can anyone have any idea about this.

FYI, I have checked firewall, we have open firewall, no restrictions.
No antivirus is installed
I can able to connect using SQL authentication but not Windows
Nothing noted in error logs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue has been fixed, there is a problem with the Active Directory. When we update group policy, issue has been fixed!